# Junit5 test multiple implementations of the same interface

Tags: java, junit5

I've got following code in IAdder.java:

```
public interface IAdder {

int add(int a, int b);
```

}

Then the following implementations (one in SimpleAdder.java and another in AbsAdder.java):

```
public class SimpleAdder implements IAdder {

@Override
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

}

```
public class AbsAdder implements IAdder {

@Override
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return Math.abs(a) + Math.abs(b);
}
```

}

Now I want to test with Junit5 so I start writing the following in SimpleAddertest.java:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class SimpleAdderTest {

```
IAdder ia = new SimpleAdder();

@Test
void add() {
    assertEquals(10, ia.add(7, 3));
}
```

}

To test AbsAdder I could add the following test class AbsAdderTest:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
```

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class AbsAdderTest {

```
IAdder ia = new AbsAdder();

@Test
void add() {
    assertEquals(10, ia.add(7, 3));
}
```

}

What's the best way to avoid this code repetition in Junit5? I ve seen other posts on SO but no one answered this simple question in a simple way.

Comment: What code repitition? They're two different implementations so you need to test both use cases. Similarly you'll need to test `add(-5,-7)` in both, though with different results.

Comment: I don't think this can be called code repetition as you are testing different implementations. There might be another implementation in future which will not give 7+3=10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `@ParameterizedTest`, where you can pass the implementation and the test cases, e.g.

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("sourceMethod")
public void test(IAdder add, int a, int b, int expected) {
    assertEquals(expected, add.add(a, b));
}

public static Stream<Arguments> sourceMethod() {
    final SimpleAdder simpleAdder = new SimpleAdder();
    final AbsAdder absAdder = new AbsAdder();
    return Stream.of(
            Arguments.of(simpleAdder, 2, 3, 5),
            // add more test cases for SimpleAdder, e.g. 
            Arguments.of(simpleAdder, 2, 0, 2),
            Arguments.of(simpleAdder, 0, 4, 4),
            Arguments.of(absAdder, -2, -5, 7),
            // add more test cases for AbsAdder, e.g. 
            Arguments.of(absAdder, -2, 0, 2),
            Arguments.of(absAdder, 0, -9, 9)
    );
}
```

Comment: don't think assertThat(add.add(a, b), equalTo(expected)); is part of Junit5?

Comment: need to change that line to assertEquals(expected, add.add(a, b));

Comment: what if I wanted to add MethodSource to all the tests in a class?

Comment: @FrancescoDassisis yeah, sorry about that, I was using hamcrest, thanks for the edit!
`import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.junit.MatcherAssert.*;`

Comment: You can have as many MethodSources and as many ParameterizedTests as you want. All JUnit cares about is having a static method which returns a Stream of Arguments and the number/type of arguments matching the signature of your parameterized test. Is this what you were asking? Maybe I haven't understood your last question?

Comment: so if I have 5 method tests I have to write 5 different static Stream<Arguments> sourceMethod().. I am assuming this is the only way

Comment: If you have 5 parameterized tests, you need a source for each one of them. It might not be the case to have 5 source methods. You can reuse them, depending on your use cases, e.g. Let's say you're working with an old API which works fine, has tests but its internals are so badly written that you create a new API which is clean, easy to maintain etc. You can have a source which is used by: old API tests, new API tests, test that compares old API vs new API head to head (published due to character limit here: https://gist.github.com/silviuburceadev/db8b76041b1c9838d0e0dc0f8e71abbe)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214403/discussion-between-silviu-burcea-and-francesco-dassisis).